# How can I konw which objects moved from young generation to old generation in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When optimizing Java memory, I tried use async-profiler to tracking memory alloc, but I still don't know which objects cause old generation raise up.

Is there some way to track object promotion event? No dump whole memory snapshot are best, it's too crushing to online server.

Comment: *"Is there some way to track object promotion event?"* - No there isn't.

Comment: When the survivor space is full, it’s not a single object’s fault. The object(s) that got promoted just happened to be the oldest by the time of garbage collection (as far as the particular implementation tracks it—it’s not a precise measurement).